# what is the minimum size for a human settlement to ensure genetic diversity?

Tags: space-colonization, population, genetic-diversity

assuming pretty good access to things like food and water, and a regular to slightly extended lifespan, would a population of ~120ish adults be enough to avoid inbreeding issues over time? basically, i have a small colony world with a much smaller than intended starting population due to catastrophe. i'm also wondering if there are any genetic concerns that might make non-typical relationship structures (polyamory of some kind, etc) more viable in the long-term, or if they'd have any effect on the long-term genetic diversity of the group.